# How to use a Tensorflow (python) custom layer with only one trainable variable?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, bessel-functions

I am looking for a way to add a custom layer to my TensorFlow (python) model. This layer should consist of one trainable variable `delta`. This variable has to be used as an argument of the bessel function `special.jn(n, delta)`. Let `input_vector` be the d-dimensional vector containing my inputs. I want this to be multiplied to `bessel_tensor`. The latter should be an (d x d)-Tensor containing the bessel functions for different orders n but all with the same trainable delta.  Now, I want to train for that delta to be optimized.

How can I achieve that?

What I've done so far:

- I created an custom layer with the desired trainable weight `delta`
- I tried to create the Tensor(/Matrix) described above. This did not work because I've not been able to adress the cells individually.
- Using the funciton `special.jn(n, delta)` in the context of tensors did not work quite well so I created a sum approaching the desired value

A minimal reproducible example would be:

```
import tensorflow as tf 
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from scipy import special
import pandas as pd
import math as math

# Define parameters
epochs = 12
batch_size = 100
test_size = 1000
training_size = 3000

# Loading training data
test_data = pd.read_csv("data/test_data.csv", delimiter=";")
test_labels = pd.read_csv("data/test_labels.csv")

train_data = pd.read_csv("data/train_data.csv", delimiter=";")
train_labels = pd.read_csv("data/train_labels.csv")

test_data = test_data[:test_size]
test_labels = test_labels[:test_size]

train_data = train_data[:training_size]
train_labels = train_labels[:training_size]


# Layer class
class BesselLayer(layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(BesselLayer, self).__init__(**kwargs)


    def build(self, input_shape):
        self.delta = self.add_weight(name="delta", shape=(1, 1), initializer="random_normal", trainable=True)


    def call(self, input_vector):
        
        # Should be a tensor of shape (d x d) with d = 2 shown below
        bessel_tensor = tf.Tensor([[special.jn(0, self.delta), special.jn(1, self.delta)], [special.jn(2, self.delta), special.jn(3, self.delta)]])

        return tf.matmul(input_vector, bessel_tensor)




# Creation of the model
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(784, activation=tf.nn.relu, input_shape=(784,))) # Dense layer 784
bessel_layer = BesselLayer()
model.add(bessel_layer) # Custom defined layer 784
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation=tf.nn.softmax)) # Output layer representing the output data


# Compile the model
model.compile(optimizer="adam", loss="sparse_categorical_crossentropy", metrics=['accuracy'])
print(model.summary())


# Fit the model
history = model.fit(train_data, train_labels, epochs=epochs, batch_size=batch_size)

# Evaluate the model
test_loss, test_accuracy = model.evaluate(test_data, test_labels)
```

This does not work because a trainable Tensor has to be defined somehow different

Comment: What does not work exactly? Do you get a python error, does your model not converge, do you get a gradient of None, etc.?

Comment: The first issue is, that evaluating `sp = special.jn(0, self.delta)` does not work as it produces an error: `NotImplementedError: numpy() is only available when eager execution is enabled.`
I guess that is because the speical.jn function cannot handle the self.delta variable because it is not a tensor itself.

Comment: Does anybody know how to use a trainable variable within the special.jn() function?

Comment: Give a look to [`tf.py_function`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/py_function) to use non tensorflow native functions. Your question is still too unclear for me to try to answer something.